# How do I ban a user using a chat command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a discord bot (discord.js v14) that has various functions like kicking users, banning users, ...

To ban user users I'm using the following code to register the ban command

```
const ban = new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('ban').setDescription('Ban member').setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers).addUserOption((option) =>
option.setName('user')
.setDescription('The user to ban')
.setRequired(true))
```

To respond to the registered command, I'm using the following code:

```
client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) =>{
  if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand) return;
  if (interaction.commandName === 'ban'){
    try{
      interaction.options.getUser('user').ban().then({ embeds:[ new EmbedBuilder().setDescription(`Succesfully banned ${interaction.options.getUser('user')}}`).setColor("#f05c51")
    ] })
    }catch{
      interaction.reply({ embeds:[ new EmbedBuilder().setDescription(`Couldn't ban user `).setColor("#f05c51")]})
  }
}})
```

But no matter what I do, it doesn't ban the user

Comment: Did you enable the appropriate gateway intents for your bot? https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents

Answer (score 1):

you can't really ban an user, you can ban a member instead, get the member using the user id then ban him

EDIT: or even better instead of using `.getUser()`, use `.getMember()`, then you can ban him